# what does [0..1] mean in Module.constants() method?

Tags: ruby

In the following code

```
Module.constants[0..1]  # => [:object, :Module]
```

What does the [0..1] mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0..1` is a range.  It's syntactic sugar for the Ruby parser to create a [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html) object.  You can do a lot with ranges, including simple iteration:

```
irb(main):003:0> (1..3).class
=> Range
irb(main):004:0> (1..3).each {|x| puts x}
1
2
3
=> 1..3
```

You can turn it into an `Array`, among other things:

```
irb(main):005:0> (1..3).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

When you use a `Range` as an `Array#[]` argument, it means you want all the elements whose index is in that range (inclusive):

```
irb(main):007:0> stuff = %w{a b c d e f}
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
irb(main):008:0> range = 2..4
=> 2..4
irb(main):009:0> stuff[range]
=> ["c", "d", "e"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Module.constants` returns an array of all the constants defined in (i.e. namespaced to) the `Module` class (yes, `Module` is a class; see `Module.class`).  The `[0..1]` says give me every element of the array from the 0th to the 1st.  In general, if `x` is an array, then `x[m..n]` returns the subarray of `x` consisting of the elements from the mth to the nth.  For example:

```
x = [36, 25, 16, 9, 4]
x[1..3] # => [25, 16, 9]
```

Comment: Module is a class, but the Class class inherits from the Module class, so your statement left me confused for a split second ;)

Comment: Haha, yeah it's weird: `Class.superclass.class == Class # => true`.